# How can i display Products Position in view.html?

Tags: magento-1.9, products-view

How can i display the products position (of the current category) in the products view.phtml?

I try

```
$_category->getProductsPosition()
and
$_product->getProductsPosition()
```

Both still won't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
$catId = end($_product->getCategoryIds());

// Returns all product ids with its position
$productPositions = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId)->getProductsPosition();
echo $productPositions[$_product->getId()];
```

Comment: Ah thank you for this awesome tip. I got it now. I only have to edit the code a bit to get the right Category and for load the position:

$catId = Mage::registry('current_product')->getCategoryId();

// Returns all product ids with its position
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($catId);
$productPositions = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category')->getProductsPosition($category);
echo $productPositions[$_product->getId()];